# How to send key presses from an action in the ViewModel to a TextBox/PasswordBox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, touchscreen

I'm trying to create a login page using Caliburn.Micro.

The application requires an on-screen keypad for the users to enter their user id and password using a touchscreen.

How can I set the keyboard.focus from the ViewModel to the textbox selected when a button is pressed on the keypad?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

1) when user touches the TextBox, if the system has on screen keyboards, it should be displayed  on its own

2) if you want to this from code, you should expose an event in your VM. Then, in the View you should subscribe to it and from there you can do `TextBox.Focus()`

Comment: yes, it's quite a myth about CB in the views - it is VERY usefull, but you have to remember to do ony view stuff there